# Capistrano on windows returns error code 256

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, capistrano

I have a ruby on rails application that i wish to deploy on a remote linux server from my windows machine. However I get the following out after running cap deploy command at the prompt

Command bundle exec rake assets:clean && EXECJS_RUNTIME='Node' JRUBY_OPTS='-J-d32 -X-C' bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned status code 256

Any ideas on what the error code means?

Comment: Most ruby gems don't really consider compatibility for Windows. I'm not sure how much you've developed RoR in Windows, but my guess it's going to come with a lot of unexplained headaches. As a result (cause or effect depending on your view), many people don't develop RoR apps in Windows, thus the amount of documentation for RoR on Windows will be slim. I think in the long run, maybe running a Linux VM in the background, while your IDE runs in Windows is the best solution.

Comment: Hi @AndrewWei :Thats true, I have had issues with a lot of gems with C extension which I got around. But I am not sure if this is a gem issue. If that error code made any sense to you, could you elaborate?

Comment: @AndrewWei: Do you pointers to how to achieve that? (running a Linux VM in teh backgroung while the IDE runs in windows?)

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ or just use a free Ubuntu Developer box at [Nitrious.io](https://www.nitrous.io/join/QBk37nUoZ_c)